# Rename [mfmailcomposeviewcontroll] to [mfmailcomposeviewcontroller]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [mfmailcomposeviewcontroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mfmailcomposeviewcontroll) tag has 836 questions and refers to a class that is actively in use in iOS development. The full name of the class is **[MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)**.

The tag had obviously been created before the character limit of tags was raised from 25 characters. I'd suggest renaming it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this was because of the 25 character limit on tag names. Now that [Shog has changed the limit to 35](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490), the tag name can be edited to that.

I have renamed the tag to [mfmailcomposeviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller), and all the 836 questions are remapped to that.

Comment: Thank you, this was quick. One more thing: can you please restore the tag wiki excerpt of the tag as well?

Comment: @the4kman, I'll remember to check again after an hour. If it's still not there, I'll restore it from the archive. (Totally weird, though. The tag wiki does get copied)

Comment: After more than an hour, it's still not there. Strange indeed...

Comment: @the4kman, I added the wiki now.

Comment: Hmm, the first para in the wiki seems plagiarized from [this page](https://github.com/ParkinT/RubyMotion_APISampler/blob/master/app/controllers/main_view_controller.rb#L79), not sure if I should roll that back.